# NSMutableDictionary and NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a such problem.
I have NSMutableDictionary

```
Object  10          Key  1
Object  20          Key  2
Object  30          Key  3
Object  40          Key  4
Object  50          Key  5
```

Then I have code

```
NSArray*currentArray=[currentMutableDictionary allValues];
```

When I output current Array I have
Value

```
20
50
30
10
40
```

How I can add obects from Dictionary to Array in the correct order ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in the correct order"? Ascending order by key? In your example the keys happen to be 1,2,3,4,5; in your actual code, can they be arbitrary? (If not, you might consider whether a dictionary is really the right data structure!)

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    int v1 = [num1 intValue];
    int v2 = [num2 intValue];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}

 NSArray *currentArray = [[currentMutableDictionary allValues] sortedArrayUsingFunction:intSort context:nil];
```

That should sort the array properly, assuming you have NSNumber objects in your dictionary.

Comment: That sorts the objects by value, rather than by key. I wonder which Anton wanted.

Answer (score 0):

you can make an NSMutableArray instead and add the objects iterating it an using addObjectAtIndex method

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the keys in sorted order using `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator`, then make a mutable array to put the values in, and extract them using `objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:`.

Comment: This asssumes you want your objects ordered by their key in the dictionary rather than their value. If you want them ordered by value, then go with Richard J. Ross III's suggestion and pull them out with `allValues` and sort them.